# Generate the correct type instead of a union in GraphQL codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, codegen, graphql-codegen

I am trying to migrate a setup which generates all the types exactly like what the server has into something which is based on just the document nodes that we've written.

I currenly have this configuration in `.graphqlrc.js`

```js
/** @type {import('graphql-config').IGraphQLConfig} */
const graphqlConfig = {
  schema: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL,
  documents: './src/graphql/**/*.ts',
  extensions: {
    codegen: {
      hooks: {
        afterAllFileWrite: ['prettier --write'],
      },
      generates: {
        './src/__generated__/graphql.ts': {
          plugins: [
            'typescript',
            'typescript-operations',
            {
              add: {
                content: '/* eslint-disable */',
              },
            },
          ],
          config: {
            disableDescriptions: true,
          },
        },
        './src/__generated__/introspection-result.ts': {
          plugins: ['fragment-matcher'],
          config: {
            useExplicitTyping: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
}
```

and this generates something like below

```js
export type QueryName = {
  __typename?: 'Query'
  resource?:
    | { __typename?: 'A' }
    | { __typename?: 'B' }
    | {
        __typename?: 'C'
        id: string
        prop1: any
        prop2: any
      }
}
```

that is not exactly what I was expecting to be generated. I am expecting something like

```js
export type QueryName = {
  __typename?: 'Query'
  resource?: {
        __typename?: 'C'
        id: string
        prop1: any
        prop2: any
  }
}
```

as I am only querying for `C`. The types that is currently getting generated will affect a lot of codes whereas if I could output what I want to achieve, we only need to change the types.

I've tried playing with the config found [here](https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/plugins/typescript-operations) but could not find a solution. Please let me know if this is possible or if there's something I could take a look at to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I eventually end up using [tiny-invariant](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tiny-invariant) package for this. Consider the ff code

```js
const {data} = useUserQuery({variables: {id}});

// more codes here...

invariant(data.user.__typename === "User");

// now we should get the type that we want here
```

Comment: I tried to make a helper function:
```function ensureType(graphqlObject, expectedTypeName) {
  invariant(graphqlObject.__typename === expectedTypeName, `Expected graphql object to be type of ${expectedTypeName}; got ${graphqlObject.__typename}`);
}```
Any idea how to make it work?

Comment: Why use tiny-invariant? You can do the same thing with an if statement

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good solution!

For example you have something like this:

```
export type GetProductQuery = {
  __typename?: 'Query'
  product?:
    | { __typename: 'NotFound'; message: string }
    | {
        __typename: 'Product'
        id: string
        title: string
        currentPrice: number
      }
    | null
}
```

Then, you can use the [Extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttu) utility type

```
type QueryProductData = Extract<GetProductQuery['product'], { __typename: 'Product' }>
type QueryNotFoundData = Extract<GetProductQuery['product'], { __typename: 'NotFound' }>
```

From these types, you can construct any type in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do

```
if (data.user.__typename === "User") { ... };
```

to ensure that its referring to the type within the union you need